# why can't i pass an async function as a field when it takes mutable references?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I was working on a structure that had asynchronous functions as fields, but it didn't work when it took mutable references.

this works:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

pub struct TestStruct;

struct TestStruct2<F>
where
    F: std::future::Future<Output = ()>,
{
    foo: fn(TestStruct) -> F,
}

async fn foo(_x: TestStruct) {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _s = TestStruct2 { foo };
}
```

this does not work:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

pub struct TestStruct;

struct TestStruct2<F>
where
    F: std::future::Future<Output = ()>,
{
    foo: fn(&mut TestStruct) -> F,
}

async fn foo(_x: &mut TestStruct) {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _s = TestStruct2 { foo }; //error here
}
```

error:

```
mismatched types
expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut TestStruct) -> _`     
found fn item `for<'r> fn(&'r mut TestStruct) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = ()> {foo}`
```

could someone explain to me why this happens and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't the `mut`, it's the reference and its lifetime. According to [the *Asynchronous Programming in Rust* book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html), the return values of `async` functions have their lifetimes bounded by their arguments' lifetimes. Your definition of `TestStruct2::foo` doesn't accept this. To fix that, you can add this lifetime explicitly to `F`:

```
struct TestStruct2<'a, F>
where
    F: std::future::Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
{
    foo: fn(&'a mut TestStruct) -> F,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `foo`'s return type has an implicit `+ 'a` bound, where `'a` is the anonymous lifetime in `&mut TestStruct`.

Simply desugaring `foo` to an explicit `impl Trait` type and an `async` block solves the issue.

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

pub struct TestStruct;

struct TestStruct2<F>
where
    F: std::future::Future<Output = ()>,
{
    foo: fn(&mut TestStruct) -> F,
}

fn foo(_x: &mut TestStruct) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = ()> {
    async {}
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _s = TestStruct2 { foo };
}
```

However, as soon as we try to use the reference from within the `async` block, errors pop up again. (It looks like the compiler moves all parameters from an `async fn` to the hidden `async` block.)

```
fn foo(_x: &mut TestStruct) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = ()> {
    async {
        _x;
    }
}
```

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Future<Output = ()>` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
12 |   fn foo(_x: &mut TestStruct) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = ()> {
   |              --------------- hidden type `impl Future<Output = ()>` captures the anonymous lifetime defined here
13 | /     async {
14 | |         _x;
15 | |     }
   | |_____^
   |
help: to declare that the `impl Trait` captures `'_`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
   |
12 | fn foo(_x: &mut TestStruct) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = ()> + '_ {
   |                                                                      ++++
```

And if we apply the compiler's suggestion, then we're back to square one:

```
fn foo(_x: &mut TestStruct) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = ()> + '_ {
    async {
        _x;
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:28
   |
20 |     let _s = TestStruct2 { foo };
   |                            ^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut TestStruct) -> _`
                 found fn item `for<'r> fn(&'r mut TestStruct) -> impl for<'r> Future<Output = ()> {foo}`
```

We can fix this by adding a lifetime parameter to `TestStruct2` and using it in the appropriate places. (We can also restore `foo` to its original form.)

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

pub struct TestStruct;

struct TestStruct2<'a, F>
where
    F: std::future::Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
{
    foo: fn(&'a mut TestStruct) -> F,
}

async fn foo(_x: &mut TestStruct) {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let s = TestStruct2 { foo };
    let mut t = TestStruct;
    (s.foo)(&mut t).await;
}
```